# How to force socat to send from a specified interface not loopback (socat so-bindtodevice NOT working)

Tags: ubuntu, networking

Objective: send/recv TCP packets from/to a specified interface on the same machine

Solution : socat ...so-bindtodevice=...

Env.     : bare-metal x86-64 running unmodified fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
box has (essentially) two interfaces: bond0 and enp1s0f1

Problem. : per tcpdump the packets are *always* sent through the loopback device.

Context :  I understand all local traffic, by construction, goes through loopback. But
I want to change this default behavior. Once I get this problem solved I want
to apply it to a SR-IOV config with TC mirroring. To test that configuration I
*must be able* to send packets from a named interface so I can confirm TC
mirrored them to right destination interface. The default loopback routing prevents
this. **This post attempts to make a procedure to send packets from a
specified interface in the simplest context possible without all the SR-IOV/TC complications.**

Procedure:

- Boot bare-metal x86-64 running unmodified fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
- Box has two Intel E810 NIC devices:

  - 01:00.0 Intel Corporation Ethernet Controller E810-XXV for SFP (rev 02)
  - 01:00.1 Intel Corporation Ethernet Controller E810-XXV for SFP (rev 02)
- Box has several network devices. The salient interface for this post:

  - enp1s0f1: 50:7c:6f:06:d8:25/192.168.0.2
- On the same machine: listen on port 2000 on enp1s0f1; send to port 2000 from enp1s0f1:

  - shell 1: socat tcp4-listen:2000,so-bindtodevice=enp1s0f1 -
  - shell 2: socat tcp4-connect:192.168.0.2:2000,so-bindtodevice=enp1s0f1 -
  - shell 3: monitor port 2000: tcpdump -i any -e -n port 2000

Expected:

- See packets flow from SRC to DST with enp1s0f1's MAC address and enp1s0f1 interface number (3):

  - SRC 50:7c:6f:06:d8:25/192.168.0.2 port xxxx
  - DST 50:7c:6f:06:d8:25/192.168.0.2 port 2000

Actual:

- Connection made and works but tcpdump reports loopback's MAC and itfc number (1):

  - 20:07:07.989278 lo    In  ifindex 1 00:00:00:00:00:00 ethertype IPv4 (0x0800),
    length 72: 192.168.0.2.2000 > 192.168.0.2.57594

I tried deleting routes from local. I tried policy based routing. In all cases either the route still goes through lo or the sender can't connect reporting error: no route. I've even written C++ code leveraging SO_BINDTODEVICE with desired interface number. However, the O/S routing rules still managed to override it with loop back. And besides socat already does SO_BINDTODEVICE.

What in the heck can I do to remove lo from the routing policy?

Answer (score 0):

**Loop back, ip route, socat etc. are all red herrings**.

All that's needed for a transmitter to send packets from a designated ethernet device known to Linux is the following bind call shown in Python which has equivalences in C/C++:

```
# import socket
# def send_tcp_packet(dev, packet):
    # Create a raw socket
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.SOCK_RAW)
    # Bind the socket to the specific Ethernet device
    # 'dev' can be a device name or IPV4 address string
    s.bind((dev, 0))
    # Send the packet
    s.send(packet)

# Example usage
send_tcp_packet("enp1s0f1", b'\x08\xc0\xeb\xd4\xebv\x08\xc0\xeb\xd4\xebv\x08\x00E\x00\x00(\x00\x01\x00\x00@\x06\xf9z\xc0\xa8\x00\x02\xc0\xa8\x00\x02\x07\xd0\x07\xd1\x00\x0fB@\x00\x0fB?P\x02 \x00zO\x00\x00')
```

tcpdump (wireshark) will indeed record the packet coming from 'dev's MAC address assuming ARP is configured right, which happens out of the box once the ethernet device is correctly configured. You can also run 'ethtool -S enp1s0f1' (stats view) and note each run of this script increments the number of transmitted packets and bytes.

Readers can use scapy (as I did) to make the binary string passed to send_tcp_packet. This is also Python code:

```
# Scapy python code 'pip3 install scapy'
e=Ether()                                                                                                               
i=IP()                                                                                                                  
t=TCP()                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                   
e.dst="08:c0:eb:d4:eb:76"                                                                                               
e.src="08:c0:eb:d4:eb:76"                                                                                               
e.type=0x0800                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                    
i.version=4                                                                                                             
i.ihl=5                                                                                                                 
i.len=40                                                                                                                
i.ttl=64                                                                                                                
i.proto=6                                                                                                               
i.src="192.168.0.2"                                                                                                     
i.dst="192.168.0.2"                                                                                                     
i.options=0                                                                                                             
i.chksum=0xf97a                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                    
t.sport=2000                                                                                                            
t.dport=2001                                                                                                            
t.seq=1000000                                                                                                           
t.ack=999999                                                                                                            
t.chksum=0x7a4f                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                    
p=e/i/t
ls(p)                                                                                                                 
print(p)                                                                                                                
raw(p)
```

To get the correct chksums in the IP and TCP layers -- here scapy is braindead --- see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953371/how-to-calculate-a-packet-checksum-without-sending-it

Once you have the right chksums you can then go back an force set them to the correct values and re-run 'raw(p)' to see the string to pass to 'send_tcp_packet' above. The scapy code I give above reflects the delete attribute and show2 work referenced in the HTML link.

Here's the stdout from scapy code:

```
Ether / IP / TCP 192.168.0.2:callbook > 192.168.0.2:dc S
>>> ls(p)
dst        : DestMACField                        = '08:c0:eb:d4:eb:76' ('None')
src        : SourceMACField                      = '08:c0:eb:d4:eb:76' ('None')
type       : XShortEnumField                     = 2048            ('36864')
--
version    : BitField  (4 bits)                  = 4               ('4')
ihl        : BitField  (4 bits)                  = 5               ('None')
tos        : XByteField                          = 0               ('0')
len        : ShortField                          = 40              ('None')
id         : ShortField                          = 1               ('1')
flags      : FlagsField                          = <Flag 0 ()>     ('<Flag 0 ()>')
frag       : BitField  (13 bits)                 = 0               ('0')
ttl        : ByteField                           = 64              ('64')
proto      : ByteEnumField                       = 6               ('0')
chksum     : XShortField                         = 63866           ('None')
src        : SourceIPField                       = '192.168.0.2'   ('None')
dst        : DestIPField                         = '192.168.0.2'   ('None')
options    : PacketListField                     = [0]             ('[]')
--
sport      : ShortEnumField                      = 2000            ('20')
dport      : ShortEnumField                      = 2001            ('80')
seq        : IntField                            = 1000000         ('0')
ack        : IntField                            = 999999          ('0')
dataofs    : BitField  (4 bits)                  = None            ('None')
reserved   : BitField  (3 bits)                  = 0               ('0')
flags      : FlagsField                          = <Flag 2 (S)>    ('<Flag 2 (S)>')
window     : ShortField                          = 8192            ('8192')
chksum     : XShortField                         = 31311           ('None')
urgptr     : ShortField                          = 0               ('0')
options    : TCPOptionsField                     = []              ("b''")
>>> raw(p)
b'\x08\xc0\xeb\xd4\xebv\x08\xc0\xeb\xd4\xebv\x08\x00E\x00\x00(\x00\x01\x00\x00@\x06\xf9z\xc0\xa8\x00\x02\xc0\xa8\x00\x02\x07\xd0\x07\xd1\x00\x0fB@\x00\x0fB?P\x02 \x00zO\x00\x00'
```